# Convert unix timestamp to human readable date in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

Sorry, This can be a repeated question.But still i didn't get the correct answer.

I have a unix timestamp '1470900186868', it should be convert into 'Thu, 11 Aug 2016 07:23:06.868 GMT' but i am always getting the same value which is 'December 20, 48580 @ 17:14:28 UTC'.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: timestamp it is integer with max value = 4294967296. I guess you have 8 bytes timestamp on 64 bit processor? Take a look on https://www.sitepoint.com/is-your-php-application-affected-by-the-y2k38-bug/

Comment: Show what you've tried so far.

Comment: That's in miliseconds, not seconds. Divide it by 1000, and then append the remainder to your string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$val = 1470900186868;

// Grab the milliseconds as the initial value mod 1000
$milliseconds = $val % 1000;

// Divide by 1000 to obtain the actual timestamp
$ts = intval($val / 1000);

// Parse into a DateTime object
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $ts);

// Formatted output
echo $date->format('D, d M Y H:i:s') . '.' . $milliseconds;
```

Comment: This has a bug in it. If the milliseconds is less than 100 then it would only have 2 digits. Instead you should append a padded string, e.g. str_pad($milliseconds,3,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);

Answer (score 2):

Did You try to use DateTime object?

```
echo (new DateTime())
    ->setTimestamp(1470900186868 / 1000)
    ->format('D, d M Y H:i:s T')
```